# Send column name from button

Tags: php, button, send

I have made a php page. On which I am displaying table 'prod' from my data base. 
 each row is displayed nicely.  Today i tried to add a button named 'rate' at the end of each row of my table. which I did successfully. Now I want to send  the the value of the first column of that row to another php page when that button is clicked. I am stuck that how to do so? can you help please ??

I know i have to use the method post in my form and i have to use `$_post[that value]` on the other php page to inculcate the value for further function.

I just need to ask that  where to add the value of my first column in the button line.  so that onclick it can send that value.  I hope I am clear over this. Thank You very much for help :)

```html
<?php 
include("connection.php");

$query = "select *  from prod"; 
$res = oci_parse($conn,$query); 
usleep(100); 
if (oci_execute($res)){ 
        usleep(100); 
       
   print "<TABLE border \"1\">"; 
        $first = 0; 
        while ($row = @oci_fetch_assoc($res)){ 
                if (!$first){ 
                        $first = 1; 
                        print "<TR><TH>"; 
                        print implode("</TH><TH>",array_keys($row)); 
                        print "</TH></TR>\n"; 
                } 
                print "<TR><TD>"; 
                print @implode("</TD><TD>",array_values($row)); 
                print "</TD></TR>\n"; 
    
            echo "<td><form action='detailform.php' method='POST'><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Rate'/></form></td></tr>";
     
  }     
        print "</TABLE>"; 

  } 
 
?>
```

Comment: Use a hidden input with the value you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add inputs in your form whatever kind u prefer

```
echo "<td>
          <form action='detailform.php' method='POST'>
               <input type='hidden' name='your_val_key' value='".$row[your_val_key_in_query]."'> <!-- input hidden, change to text 4 debug -->
               <input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Rate'/>
          </form>
      </td></tr>";
```

and than, in your `detailform.php` u can get the val with

```
echo $_POST["your_val_key"];
```

if u are not sure how much data u send or somthing, try this and u get the full data:

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";
```

BTW: why are u mixing print and echo?

Comment: No! sorry it was by mistake.  i am just trying to figure out something. please can you help me over some other issue in this code??  I even am unable to find the value of my column to place in  'your_value _key_in query'.  can you help me with this??    what i  did is   i replaced 'your_value _key_in_query' with $row[1]   to get column 1 from row. bt it gave error. "undefined offset 0"  can you help me.

Comment: just use the column name from your select, the column name in the table. if one of your column name is "extradata" then you have to use `$row["extradata"]` - btw array_keys puts your column names out as well

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden input

```
echo "<td><form action='detailform.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='col-name' value='you-col-value'><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Rate'/></form></td></tr>";
```